# I can't install pip with yum, do you know the following error?

Tags: pip, yum, fiware

An errors occurs when i try to install pip (for example):

```
sudo yum install python-pip 

Complementos cargados:fastestmirror, presto Configurando el proceso de instalación Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile 
* base: mirror.gadix.com 
* epel: mirror.airenetworks.es 
* extras: mirror.gadix.com * updates: mirror.gadix.com repositories.lab.fiware.org/repo/rpm/6/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found" Intentando con otro espejo. 
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Fiware. Please verify its path and try again
```

Comment: This is off-topic for here - you would be better off over at [su] but it looks like its just a `404` not found error from that repo. You could try `yum clean all` and try again. It also may be the far end is down and to try again later.

Comment: It doesn't work :(

Comment: `python-pip` is provided by `epel` repo (at least on CentOS6 & 7)

Answer (score 0):

Usually if you are working with Ubuntu system, you should use apt-get or apt to install software and not yum. The only commands that you need to execute are basically update the apt and then install the python-pip package:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python-pip
```

In case of CentOS, you should use yum but in that case the first thing that you need to do is the installation of the EPEL repo in which the python-pip package is located. Afterwards, you need to update yum and finally install the package.

```
sudo yum -y install epel-release
sudo yum -y update
sudo yum -y install python-pip
```