# Cannot install python-pip using yum in Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, installation, yum

I have the error message

```
failure: repodata/repomd.xml from HDP-2.6-repo-1: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://public-repo-1.hortonworks.com/HDP/centos7/2.x/updates/2.6.5.0/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 403 - Forbidden
```

when using the command

```
# yum install python-pip
```

While trying to install the package through putty it showed the same kind of error.

Can you help me fix this problem?

Comment: Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37954008/proper-way-to-install-pip-on-ubuntu

Comment: Please check this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58141892/hortonworks-sandbox-2-5-yum-install-python-pip-not-working

Comment: @VSCloud9 the above link was not help full.it was showing apt is not available like that

Comment: @Deniz here it was show no such a file or directory available like that error.I have a doubt how in can create those file in that directory can you please guide me

Comment: Could you try this: `# yum --disablerepo=REPONAME repolist`

Comment: @Deniz I have used ```ls``` to find the files available there is only one data u.data that is a kind of dataset I have uploaded in Hadoop except that there is nothing is there how I can create needed files?? Thank you for your response

Comment: No I don't think so. If you are installing a library the package manager should do everything by itself. Can you try the above code like this: `yum --disablerepo=HDP repolist`

Comment: Error getting repository data for HDP, repository not found
getting this kind of error

Comment: Can you try this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54416846/1549080

Comment: yeah i tried every solution... I have found a solution...i will post it in answer

Comment: Thank you @Deniz for you response to the question

Comment: You're welcome. Enjoy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using those two commends make a configuration.then install python:

`yum-config-manager --save --setopt=HDP-SOLR-2.3-100.skip_if_unavailable=true`

```
yum install https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-e17.rpm https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm
```

Install python :
`yum install python-pip`